# Div removed with jQuery still exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I've got an old application in ASP.NET. In a form with a Submit button, I put this div at the top of the page:

```
<div id="submitIndication" class="saveIndication" runat="server" visible="false">
    Your request has been submitted.
</div>
```

On btnSubmit_Click in the code-behind, I put this line:

```
submitIndication.visible = true
```

This code then handles a fading out of the div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(fadeOut, 4000);
});

function fadeOut() {
    jQuery("#submitIndication").slideUp(400);
};
```

That all works fine. However, there are two other buttons on the page, "Prefill Form" and "Opt Out". These call their own methods (btnOptOut_Click and btnPrefillFormInfo_Click), neither of which touches the submitIndication div in any way.

But, after I submit the form the first time, when I click Prefill Form or Opt Out, the page refreshes, and the submit div appears at the top again. If I click them *before* submitting, this doesn't happen.

It seems the div is still on the page at this point, and just displaying until the JavaScript fades it out. I've tried all manner of things (setting CSS visible to false and display to none, remove(), hide(), attr(), etc.), and nothing seems to get rid of this div.

This feels like it should be so simple. How can I get this div to *not* show up after a submit and clicking other buttons?

Comment: Javascript values dont transfer between pages

Comment: If you're refreshing the page .... then all values restart.

Comment: I don't understand. Which values? Wouldn't stuff like visible=false being set by JavaScript set the div back to the way it was, and transfer between pages? Or is that my problem?

I guess I'd need to do this server-side. I'm at a bit of a loss to how to do that, though.

Comment: That JS is not transfer between pages.

Comment: You'll definitely have to do something server-side, use cookies, or forgo refreshing the page altogether. The easiest method is probably simply making a whole new page for after submitting. The most aesthetically pleasing is probably to use AJAX to submit and then use a callback to change the page after the submission.

Comment: I'm also not exactly sure what you mean when you say that clicking the Prefill Form or Opt Out button before submitting does not make the `div` appear. At any rate, it's worth keeping in mind that HTTP is stateless. Hence you have to rely on additional client-side tricks (e.g. cookies) or server-side storage to achieve stateful transactions.

Comment: That helps. Just seems needlessly complicated for a simple "This worked!" notification, but I guess that's how things go...

Anyway, the div is set visible=false at first. Prefill Form and Opt Out shouldn't trigger visible=true, which is good. It looks like the problem isn't so much with those buttons but with the fact that they refresh the page.

Comment: FYI this isn't classic ASP. This is ASP.NET

Comment: Right you are... got confused there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Declare DIV as:

```
<div id="submitIndication" class="saveIndication" runat="server" style="display:none">
    Your request has been submitted.
</div>
```

And on btnSubmit_Click in the code-behind put this line (assuming u're using C#):

```
submitIndication.Style["display"] = "block";
```

And use your current fadeout code.

**Update** Come to think of it even simpler approach should work. Keep everything as it is in your setup, just add `EnableViewState = "false"` to your DIV's HTML definition.

Comment: The second solution (in your update) worked like a charm. I'm curious how that works?

Comment: Yes I had a feeling that the first one may not be enough. What is happening here - initially when you set `visible="false"` the DIV is not rendered in HTML at all. When you set `visible = true` in code-behind - it renders, then you hide it in JS code - but you hide it on client only. When page posts back - client-side changes are lost, but `visible = true` persists because by default control's ViewState keeps the changes. Disabling ViewState disregards those changes as well.